# how image can stay aspect ratio with two dimension?

Tags: css

Problem: img is taller than `img-box`

[image]

I find two ways, but I don't want to do this:

1. remove `img-box` wrap
2. use `max-height: 100vh; max-width: 100vw;` in img tag

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img-box {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="img-box">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/900/500" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="img-box">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/600" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

([Codesandbox](https://nmfl05.csb.app/))

Comment: Try adding `height: 100%` on image, and give `img-box` height (i.e `height: 100vh;`)

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

On `img-box` set height to `100%` instead of `auto`.

That way `img` will not stretch `img-box` outside the boundaries of its parent.

---

You can also set height to a definite value, like `height: 100px`.

Comment: u can show demo with that, it doesn't work in x dimension

Comment: @flyflydogdog If you want `img` to cover the `img-box` container completely, you need to add `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` to `img`  with an addition of `object-fit` to prevent `img` from stretching.

https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-lalande-ggdqq7?file=/index.html